# Consulta Banco de Dados entre tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Banco de dados possui 4 tabelas

```
tabela 1
|escola|descricao|

tabela 2
|matricula|nome|estado|

tabela 3
|matricula|escola|posicao|

tabela 4
|matricula|diretor|nome
```

Eu preciso fazer uma pesquisa por estado (na tabela 2) e que retorne os resultados:

> matricula, nome, escola e descrição

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Tentei ser claro no que foi possível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai precisar da cláusula `JOIN`, que faz justamente a junção de resultados de pesquisa baseado em critérios de busca.

Neste seu caso, a consulta ficaria:

```
SELECT
    TB2.matricula,
    TB2.nome,
    TB1.escola,
    TB1.descrição
FROM
    tabela2 AS TB2
    JOIN tabela3 AS TB3 ON TB3.matricula = TB2.matricula
    JOIN tabela1 AS TB1 ON TB1.escola = TB3.escola;
```